# creating web service in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

I have just little background in web and I need to do this task by myself so I will be most grateful for your help
this is what my boss told me to do (as far as I understand) - I have to write a web service server which gets some parameters, check their validity and then insert/update them in a database. All the parameters are delivered together as a packet written in SOAP - WSDL file. I have to do it using vb.NET in Visual Studio 2010. I read a bit about it and if I understand correctly .NET  takes care already of the SOAP an WSDL issue, it is transparent to me, isn't it? or should I install or implement anything concerning that?  I saw some examples in the net that all you have to do is to implement web_method in the asmx file, is it so? if yes, which parameters will my method get - the whole bunch of 20 parametres supposed to be in the packet? anything I need to declare or to update in order to connect to the DB? Any help will be appreciated - uf the answer is too long I will be happy just to get a pointer to some relevant material I can read and learn.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301273)  MSDN article: it describes how to write a simple Web service by using Visual Basic .NET

Here are the main steps from the linked MSDN article:

> 1. Start Visual Studio .NET or Visual Studio.
> 2. Create a new Active Server Pages (ASP) .NET Web service project. Name the Web service MathService and point the location to an
>      appropriate Web server that is running ASP.NET if necessary.
> 3. Change the name of the Solution file to MathService for consistency.
> 4. Change the name of the default Web service that is created from Service1.asmx to MathService.asmx.
> 5. Click Click here to switch to code view in the designer environment to switch to code view.
>
>    Change the name of the class from Public Class Service1 to Public
>      Class MathService.
> 6. Define methods that encapsulate the functionality of your service. Each method that will be exposed from the service must be flagged with
>      a WebMethod attribute in front of it. Without this attribute, the
>      method will not be exposed from the service.
> 7. Click Build on the Build menu to build the Web service.
> 8. Browse to the MathService.asmx Web service page to test the Web service. If you set the local computer to host the page, the URL is
>      http://localhost/MathService/MathService.asmx.